# how to use semi-space (unicode U+2005) in php regex

Tags: php, regex, unicode

I have a regex in php that detects a hashtag and the word after it.
So that I can use the word as a tag in post and search and so on...

This is my regex:

```
        if( preg_match_all('/\#([א-תآ-یÀ-ÿ一-龥а-яا-یa-z0-9\-_]{1,50})/iu', $message, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER) ) {
    foreach($matches[1] as $tg) {
        $this->posttags[]   = mb_strtolower(trim($tg));
    }
}
```

What I want is this regex to include the semi-space (1/4 space o Unicode U+2005)
[info](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-word/half-space-semi-space-between-words/75bfe733-fe45-47c8-a935-88ffb8848098) because it is so useful in Persian(Farsi).

Comment: i insist that only semi-space not all kind of space only semi-space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the escape character `\x{2005}` in your regex.

Test: https://regex101.com/r/hG7rN3/1

Comment: PHP7 will allow `\u{2005}` in strings for Unicode codepoints [RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/unicode_escape)

Comment: Thanks @MarkBaker - good info :) Finally some consistency changes.

Comment: @Half Crazed thank you , but way it still don't work for me ? https://regex101.com/r/fF4bY7/2

Comment: @Mr.5hady I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to match. You may need to ask another question that specifically deals with matching whatever it is you're dealing with.

Comment: i found it sorry my unicode was wrong the right unicode that i need is \x{200C}